# Python how to hack input

Tags: python, python-2.7, security

Ive heard that using "input" was unsafe for password use because it interprets the input as code, and thus someone could bypass the security.

How would you go around doing that? For example, how would you do it to something like this?

```
password = 1234

pass_true = input("What is the password?")

if password == pass_true:
    print("Access granted.")
else: 
    print ("Access denied.")
```

Comment: Do you know how SQL injection attacks work?

Comment: Having the password unencrypted in the code is unsafe as anything else. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Python 2 has `raw_input()`, which is just like `input()` except that it returns a string and does _not_ evaluate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simple: To get past your check, just type `password` at the prompt :-) Try it!

```
What is the password?password
Access granted.
```

Explanation: `input` reads what you type, *evaluates it* as python code, and assigns the result to `pass_true`. So in the above, I just told it to assign the value of the variable `password` (which holds the real password) to `pass_true`.

But this code is broken even for regular use: If you type anything that doesn't look like a valid python expression, it'll trigger an error. Your example uses numbers as "passwords", but you couldn't use the same approach for arbitrary-text passwords: It wouldn't work at all, even with the correct password.

Another kind of problem is typing something damaging like `os.remove(".profile")` (or something worse and more elaborate) at the prompt. It won't log them in but you can see the damage it can do. Evaluating user input is just wrong, unless you're writing an interactive python interpreter.

Python 2 has `raw_input()` which just reads input. (In python 3, `raw_input()` has been renamed to `input()` and the old `input()` is gone).

Comment: To type `1234`, you have to know the password. To type `password`, you have to have seen the code, but not the current password.

Comment: Yes of course, but you know ... http://blogs.wsj.com/digits/2015/01/20/123456-again-the-most-popular-passwords-arent-changing/ My comment was more of a witticism than of a real answer.

Comment: Sure, this password is easy to guess. But I was answering the question, which is about the problems `input()` introduces.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is not to keep passwords at all. You have to create hash out of input and check whether it's equal to your password's hash. But if you're just a beginner it's okay to do what you do.

Comment: This is correct as far as the use of plaintext passwords goes, but it does not extend to the use of `input()`.

Answer (score 0):

So I was [just reading this](https://medium.com/@GallegoDor/python-exploitation-1-input-ac10d3f4491f#.hwebsipr6) and if you're using Python 3.x, you'll be fine.

Otherwise, if you use input(), then you could just type `password` and be done.

Again, if you're using Python 3.x, don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

The side-channel attack sboutzen mentioned is a real threat, and can be exploited using time(), from linux command-line

This article explains it in more detail
https://blog.sqreen.com/developer-security-best-practices-protecting-against-timing-attacks/

The hash could be compromised by identifying the hash used byte by byte. You would have the hash of the real password instead of the password itself, but that is why dictionary attacks are useful.

Comment: it would be better if you provide detailed explanation as the given link might be taken out not work in future, this will make your anser irrelevant in future

Answer (score -1):

Another problem you will have with that approach is that when you compare two strings like that, you leak information and set yourself up for a side-channel attack.

The string comparison will compare the two strings one byte at a time, and if one of the bytes don't match, it returns. However, this means that an attacker knows exactly which part, of the password he is testing, is correct, and which part is not. Therefore he can reduce the entropy of a given password to 2 to the power of the length of the set of characters allowed.

When comparing passwords you should compare the two strings bytewise like so:

```
result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < storedUserPass.length; i++) {
   result |= storedUserPass[i] ^ incomingPasswordBytes[i];
}
```

When it is done, if result is equal to 0, all the bytes match, if not, they dont. This is a constant time calculation, which doesn't leak any information

Comment: What makes you think that "an attacker knows exactly which part of the password is correct"? Running the OP's code doesn't leak any such information unless you run it in a debugger-- in which case you can also just bypass authentication altogether.

Comment: Here is an example: http://verboselogging.com/2012/08/20/a-timing-attack-in-action

Comment: Well, that's interesting, you should add it to the answer.  But "exactly" in a huge exaggeration.  Also the problem disappears if passwords are hashed.

Comment: No it is not exagerated, and no hashing does not solve anything.

Comment: Hashing means you cannot solve one plaintext character at a time. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The problem is not with what you compare, it is with what speed you compare. If the string comparison used to compare arbitrary strings / hashes is not constant in time, you are vulnerable to this attack.

Comment: Sigh... so I try a bunch of passwords and find one whose hash matches the first character of your password's hash. What am I going to do now, hash passwords at random in search of hashes that begin with the same letter? Unless I have a rainbow table that includes your password (or one with the same hash), that's a non-starter.